# Glide 4.10.0 : java.lang.IllegalStateException: GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl is implemented incorrectly

Tags: android, android-glide, appglidemodule

I am getting error while using **Glide 4.10.0**

This is the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl is implemented incorrectly. If you've manually implemented this class, remove your implementation. The Annotation processor will generate a correct implementation.
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No, Still not. if you will not find solution then please try the below answer.

Comment: In my case it happens because of google-map-v3-beta sdk. When i downgraded back to V2 it works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### First thing:

Have you changed `annotationProcessor` dependency:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
```

Also, it is critical that implementation & annotationProcessor version number is the same.  *Gradle will update the first automatically but not the second.*

### Second things:

Have you added proguard rules as follow:

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
```

Hope it will helps you. Thank you.

Comment: I was using glide 4.11.0, and faced similar issue. As what @PratikButani answered, make sure implementation & annotationProcessor version number is the same.

Comment: Sant a small bounty for amazing answer

Comment: Thank you so much :) :) @Fattie You made my day and I reached 50k reputations.

Comment: UNFORTUNATELY THEY CAP IT AT 500 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! +1000000 HERE !!! THANKZZZZ!

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this bug happened when I tried to show a Google Map in my app. 
Specifically `google-map-v3-beta` SDK.

> It looks like the SDK contains an obfuscated version of Glide that
>   breaks when the app also uses Glide and the final AndroidManifest.xml
>   contains a meta-data element called "GlideModule".

There is an issue for that in the google tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132323222

**Solution for me was to switch back to maps v2.**

Comment: The same thing happened to me!

Comment: It's been 2 years already and the issue is still there.

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar issue with my apps. I upgraded Glide library from 4.9.0 to 4.11.0.

**Before:**

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.9.0'){
    exclude group: 'glide-parent'
}
```

**After:**

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0'){
    exclude group: 'glide-parent'
}
```

That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug too. Probably you are using a library that used another Glide version, so you should use the same as the version of the Glide library that your library used it.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to put the version compiler the same version in glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

Answer (score 0):

Add this to android/build.gradle.

```
  buildscript {
   ext {
    excludeAppGlideModule = true
   }
```

link:

https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/670
https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/318